# How to build a ftp server

Tags: c#, ftp

I'd like to build an home FTP SERVER - that will store all my files and the rest of my computers will upload and download files to and from it.

I don't like to start from scratch, do you know of a c# ftp server implementation?
Can you give me some guidelines of where to start what I should know etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a few of your comments why do you not just enable the FTP server through IIS on one of your computers in your network, or just enable file sharing? These things are already partof/included in Windows at your disposal.

Comment: good to know... somehow, I always ignored the ftp option when I've configured the IIS.

Answer (score 2):

You say you don't want to start from scratch, so use something that's already been through the pain:  http://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: +1 Brilliant project, I believe that if I'll get over the basics it will be a great source. Yet its in C\C++... which I can read but not write ;)

Nonetheless after searching for a client... not finding.. building my own... I'll be able to get new ideas for my client

Thanks
Asaf

Answer (score 0):

The FTP RFCs for the protocol specification and the [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespace.

And read as much as you can on security (mailing list, bulletins, books, ...) because you can very easily leave holes for anyone to get to your files.

(I don't know of any FTP libraries beyond what .NET includes (I've not needed any FTP), but there are also third party networking component libraries that may include richer functionality. You'll likely still need to understand what's going on for debugging.)

Comment: Right now I don't know how stupid my question is, but I kind of hoped to use the ftp protocol for home use only (on my home wi-fi network), if you say I must go though the internet... well I'll need something else to transfer my files... So is it possible to keep it intranet and it not do you know other file transfer protocol? (I have windows(7 and server) and osx/ios)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand the protocol: RFC959

Here a basic server in C#: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ivar/FTPServer12072005041005AM/FTPServer.aspx

Read on security...